# Iterate list elements within a class and present into new class

Tags: c#, list, class, iteration

Sorry about the inadequate information i provided originally

Here is my updated code sample and formatted.

**EmployeeClass object**

```
public class EmployeeClass
{
public int EId {get; set;}
public int EName {get; set;}
public List<Department> DeptList {get; set;}
public List<Area> AreaList {get; set;}
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }        
}
public class Area
{
    public int AreaID { get; set; }
    public string AreaName { get; set; }        
}
```

The requirement here is, I want to return the output class sortedEmployeeClass in a such a way that it will return List of sortedEmployeeClass object by expanding Department and Area

**sortedEmployeeClass object extending EmployeeClass**

```
public class sortedEmployeeClass : EmployeeClass
{
public string DepartmentName {get; set;}
public string  AreaName{get; set;}
}
```

The original object(**EmployeeClass**) has list of Employees with Department and Area as lists

But I want to return my destination object (**sortedEmployeeClass**) as List of Employees with Department Names , Area Names as strings

Hope this gives more visibility of what im looking for. Please let me know if you need more info.

For example
If Department list has HR, Safety etc... & Area list has Facility1 and Facility2 etc...
My expected output would be....

```
EId Ename DepartmentName AreaName
1   Joe   HR             Facilty1
1   Joe   Safety         Facilty1
2   Jill  HR             Facilty2
2   Jill  Safety         Facilty2
```

Comment: You don't have enough details to get you question answered. In the input you have Lists of objects, in the output it's just a string, we can't infer how you expect to transform a list of type `Department` into a string, we don't even know what properties a `Department` has.

Comment: **Unclear what you're asking.** - How is the `DeptList` and `AreaList` supposed to map to individual strings `eDept` and `eArea`? BTW, please use proper naming conventions. Property names start with an Uppercase letter. And please post the code you already tried. StackOverflow is not an automatic homework resolver.

Comment: I not understand it :/ downvoted.

Comment: You need to provide this:  `iterate the Department & Area list` - why?; `and want to provide the output` - what exactly the output should represent , the department, the employee, the something else. Although I think, I know what you mean - you want to look into departments and areas and select one in each and return an employee based on criteria. But we don't know what you looking for, hence confusion

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob I updated with more info. Basically what im looking for is, How to iterative multiple LISTS inside a class and generate unique combination of List. (by doing Cartesian / permutation combination of list1,list2,list3). have to consider those lists can be empty. sometimes. Please let me know if its still not clear. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value objects (VOs) are wrong, but using the same structure that you proposed the code is like this (remember, you need to create a list of employees):

```
//this is the list with combinations 
//---------------------------\/
List<sortedEmployeeClass> sortedList = new List<sortedEmployeeClass>();

foreach (var employee in employeeList)
{
   foreach(var department in employee.DeptList)
   {
      foreach(var area in employee.AreaList)
      {
          sortedEmployeeClass sorted = new sortedEmployeeClass();
          sorted.EId = employee.EId;
          sorted.EName = employee.EName;
          sorted.DepartmentName = department.Name;
          sorted.AreaName = area.AreaName;
          sortedList.Add(sorted);
      }
   }
}
```